# Grunt include - different config for dev(serve) and prod(dist) mode

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am struggling with [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes) task, I wish to have 2 different task depends on configuration, ex:

```
    includes: {
        server: {
                    files: {
                        src: ['index.html'], // Source files
                        dest: '.tmp/', // Destination directory
                        cwd: 'app',
                        flatten: true
                    },
                    options: {
                        silent: true,
                        banner: '<!-- I am a <% includes.files.dest %> -->'
                    }
        },
        build: {
                    files: {
                        src: ['index.html'], // Source files
                        dest: 'dist', // Destination directory
                        cwd: 'app',
                        flatten: true
                    },
                    options: {
                        silent: true,
                        banner: ''
                    }
        }
});
```

and

```
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'configureProxies',
        'includes:server',<======
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});



grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'includes:build', <======
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Unfortunately both tasks return 
**"Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'dest' of undefined)."**

Any idea why it happens?
grunt-include v 0.4.0

==================== SOLUTION ==============

I found solution on Github [github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes/issues/17](http://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes/issues/17)

Comment: I found solution on Github https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes/issues/17